# What happens if i don't pass a parameter in .then() function, what will it return

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

i have learned that .then() is a higher-order function— it takes two callback functions as arguments. We refer to these callbacks as handlers. When the promise settles, the appropriate handler will be invoked with that settled value.
i want to know that what will .then() method will return if neither parameter is passed.

Comment: `undefined` will be returned implicitly if no return is made, but `then` itself always returns a `Promise`. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) Source

Comment: Did you try doing this?  What did it return?

Comment: Always is surprising how simple it is to try and so many of these questions show now attempt.

Answer (score 3):

Than that part of the chain gets skipped completely, and the chained promise will resolve to what the previous promise resolved.

```js
Promise.resolve(1).then().then(console.log); // 1
Promise.reject(1).then().catch(console.log); // 1
```